# How can I install Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 drivers?

Tags: drivers, intel-wireless

First time trying Ubuntu and the wireless is not recognized. Can someone point me to directions how to install the wireless drivers? It is an Intel Dual Band Wireless - AC 3165. Thanks!

```
kevin@kevin-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ uname -r
3.19.0-25-generic

kevin@kevin-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    6.436555] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    6.494627] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-12.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.494641] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-11.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.494649] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.494651] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode' failed.
[    6.494659] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.494660] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode' failed.
[    6.494661] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

First, verify that you have these two files; iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode and iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode:

```
ls /lib/firmware | grep 7265
```

If so, we are going to make copies but rename them:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode  iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode  iwlwifi-3165-13.ucode
```

Reboot. Is the wireless working? If not, again let us see:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

I am not at all confident this will work prior to kernel 4.2.

To copy the downloaded files on your desktop, please right-click them and select 'Extract Here' if not done already. Then open a terminal and do:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30-13.0/iwl* /lib/firmware
```

This will copy both of the ucode files to /lib/firmware. Then proceed with the steps I outlined above.

If you haven't the files to rename, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware
cd ~/iwlwifi-firmware/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265*  /lib/firmware
```

Then rename and proceed as above.

Comment: I don 't know how to format pretty:

kevin@kevin-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ ls /lib/firmware | grep 7265

iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode

Comment: I found and downloaded iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode and iwlwifi-7265D-14.code from https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

Comment: You need -13; not -14. Do you need some help transferring and renaming them?

Comment: I don't have -13. I have -10 and -12

Comment: I downloaded the -13 files and they are on my desktop. Please help in copying.

Comment: Tried to copy into /lib/firmware, it said cannot create regular file, permission denied

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Tried. No luck.

Comment: Is this going to work in Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4 LTS? Where to get these files at the first place?

Comment: @Ashu The answer just below says it does.

Comment: @chili555 thanks. Looked into this location "https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware" it seems it is for 3160 and not 3165. It's worth taking the risk to install the wifi driver though I don't get everything 100%

Comment: @Ashu The 3165 is known to work perfectly in 15.10. I suggest you save yourself the heartache and install it.

Comment: Not working in ubuntu desktop 14.0.4 after following this solution. I had 15.10 but i need to reinstall 14.0.4 for my needs. Even after reboot this is not working. How one is getting the files from this place? "https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware". I am doing wget or save file as from the browser and I can figure out the file is type html though it should be data.

Comment: Even if i download it from here "http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi/" it doesn't  have that "iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode" files....any help where to get those files from?

Comment: A. Thanks you for the great answer for us linux n00bs.  B. This answer works on Fedora 22.  Can confirm.

Comment: The edit is too small to propose, but `cd ~/iwlwifi-firmware/firmware` should be `cd iwlwifi-firmware/firmware`. We sould not assume a directory.

Comment: In 2020 this fix still works on Lubuntu 20.04 on an Intel NUC with the 3165 wifi card.