# Ubuntu 15.10 Live won't boot - Nouveau and Nvidia

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, 15.10

### Overview

Installing Ubuntu 15.10 and when trying to boot into a live version of the install, the boot hangs and returns the following after mounting and the like.

```
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
```

and proceeds on to just give me the watchdog error about the CPU getting stuck

```
NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! [plymouthd:234]
```

### My current system specs are

```
Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.6 GHz
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
Intel HD Graphics 530
Samsung 950 SSD (NVMe) 
HGST HDD
16.0 GB RAM 
UEFI Bios
Killer e2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Intel AC3165 Dualband wireless card
```

The most important one (and problem causing in my mind) is the Intel AC3165 wireless card. I had problems with it and drivers in 14.04 but was able to work around with some manual labor ([here is the fix I used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672700/how-can-i-install-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3165-drivers)). Though I know how to fix this once I'm in a live system, I can't seem to even get that far.

I would like to stay in 15.10 instead of installing 14.04, fixing, and then updating to 15.10.

### My thoughts so far

Drivers are probably not the problem this time. [Kernel 4.1+ should support this wireless card by default](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) and I'm not getting any iwlwifi errors about loading any particular driver (like what I had in 14.04).

#### Other boot notes

It throws a hissy fit about my SSD/NVME drive being mounted in windows (windows is holding on to the meta cache and Ubuntu is claiming its in "Hibernate Mode" even though it's been shut down properly).

Systemd returns the error/warning:
    `[/lib/systemd/system/casper.service:10] Failed to parse input specifier, ignoring: force-tty`

Let me know if you need any more information!

#### Updates

Booted into single user mode and it got me to a command line. However, it froze there after a second or two.

Tried making a quick version of ARCH linux to see if I could replicate the problem, similar thing happened. Booted to command line and froze.

Booted into Ubuntu 14.04 without much issue. No wifi card and iwlwifi throws `no suitable firmware found` during boot as expected. Seems like maybe it is a kernel problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple different problems and solutions here.

Problems with Windows holding on to the cache and nvme drive were solved by disabling fast startup on Windows per recommendation 3 [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/145904).

Fixed booting problem caused by Nouveau and nvidia by pressing `e` during the grub menu and adding `nomodeset` to the end of the Linux line. System boots properly now and as expected,  no problem from the WiFi drivers. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1648380