# Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB stuck on boot?

Tags: boot, 16.04, live-usb

I want to test drive U LTS, but I can't get into the Live environment. I'm getting stuck during boot (the same issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728631/ubuntu-15-10-live-wont-boot-nouveau-and-nvidia), though just the first one):

```
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
```

and the solution involves "pressing `e` during the grub menu and adding `nomodeset` to the end of the Linux line." However, since I'm just booting from live (remember I want to test first), I don't have grub, just the default boot menu.

How can I edit whatever is being modified with the commands above, so that it's built into the USB?

Comment: Hi. Do you use UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: Hi, @MarkYisri! I use UEFI.

Comment: Press `e` during the live boot menu.

Comment: Wow, that simple--thanks so much. Now, graphics were crap, as you probably guessed (couldn't go higher than 800*600 res)--I opened the App Center and installed the nvidia drivers, but that didn't help. Will I be able to get proper graphics/resolution once installed?

Comment: @MarkYisri: Will you be submitting an answer? I will create a new question (referencing this one), I think it would be better if it had an actual answer. If not, let me know, and I'll submit one, crediting you.

Comment: I will submit an answer, can you please tell me where the question is.

Comment: Well, it's the last bit, which you answered by mentioning that for UEFI, I have to press 'e' from the live menu. The follow-up question will be how to get working nvidia drivers (using your comment, I got 16.04 installed and loading, but with 800x600 res)—there are so many posts I'm not sure what the right answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UEFI Ubuntu USB images also use GRUB. Simply press `e` during the bootup menu to fix the problem.