# Intel Wirless Dual band 3165 Configuration

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

I tried following below link for installing wireless drivers, but still no joy

[How can I install Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672700/how-can-i-install-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3165-drivers)

```
magesh@magesh-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/Downloads/linux-4.4.1$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    9.579767] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-12.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.579781] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-11.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.579792] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode failed with error -2
[    9.579794] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode' failed.
[    9.580322] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    9.700855] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v12, firmware is v13.
```

All i understood from the link is, copying two driver files, Please advice how handle other firmware load.

Still Wireless is not working for me after restarting the system.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Rename 7265-12 to 3165-12, if that rmane works. The kernel does not support 13.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: What's the output of `uname -r`? Do you have the package `linux-firmware` installed?

Comment: @DavidFoerster The problem is that there is no firmware for 3165 anywhere. The other answer offers to rename 7265.

Comment: Thanks for kind response, the kernel version is 3.19.0-25-generic. And Download Linux-4.4.1, but dont know how to update it.

Comment: Downloaded file is available in following directory /home/magesh/Downloads/linux-4.4.1.

Comment: Since the linked question suggests the installation of a kernel version ≥4.1 and you're on Ubuntu 14.04, I suggest you upgrade your kernel to the backported kernel 4.2 of Wily: `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily` and reboot. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

This will work on your current kernel

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.17.12.0.tgz
tar zxvf iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.17.12.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.17.12.0
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3165-12.ucode
```

Reboot

Comment: I was wrong with firmware api. this is the correct solution.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left.