# Follow up question to "How can I install Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 drivers?"

Tags: drivers, intel-wireless

This is a followup question to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/672700/743263).

I followed the steps written in the answer, but still the wifi won't work.

I had the two files iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode and iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode, so I renamed them as indicated, but after the reboot the wifi doesn't work.

This is the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[   24.302073] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.333982] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.333992] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.333996] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
[   24.497409] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   24.508114] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[   24.510423] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   24.510817] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   24.577697] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   25.075855] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

**EDIT** as required this is the output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: rfkill list all

Comment: @chili555 added

Comment: Does the wireless work if do do: sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop?

Comment: @chili555 yes everything works fine now, thanks