# wireless adaptors invisible to lubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, lubuntu, intel

I'm running lubuntu 18.04 64-bit on a Trekstor Surfbook a13b. It is dual-booted with Windows 10, where, hardware-wise, everything works perfectly.

The Problem: Lubuntu can't find any wi-fi adaptors, at all – at least with what I've tried. The same problem persists with various other live-distributions (lubuntu 16.04, ubuntu 18.04, ubuntu mate 18.04 – i can imagine that there's not going to be big differences between those, but still)

Windows says the wi-fi unit is an "Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165", which is supposed to work out of the box in linux (or is at least not supposed to be a huge pain to get to work).

I've tried disabling Secure Boot, and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672700/how-can-i-install-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3165-drivers) (including getting newer firmware from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)).

To have internet access for troubleshooting, I also plugged in a "devolo wifi stick ac", which works like a charm in Windows, but, same as the internal Intel device, doesn't show up at all in lubuntu 18.04.

As of now, I don't have any means at all to connect to the internet under lubuntu.

Could it be a "general PCI/USB bus error", as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot) (top answer, under "Identifying the exact hardware")?

Thanks in advance for any help at all!

Some outputs:

uname -r

```
4.15.0-20-generic
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31f0 (rev 03)
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 318c (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3184 (rev 03)
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 03)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 319a (rev 03)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 31e3 (rev 03)
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31d8 (rev f3)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 31a8 (rev 03)
00:16.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31ac (rev 03)
00:16.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31ae (rev 03)
00:16.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b0 (rev 03)
00:16.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b2 (rev 03)
00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b4 (rev 03)
00:17.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b6 (rev 03)
00:17.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31b8 (rev 03)
00:17.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31ba (rev 03)
00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31bc (rev 03)
00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31be (rev 03)
00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31c0 (rev 03)
00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31ee (rev 03)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31c2 (rev 03)
00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31c4 (rev 03)
00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 31c6 (rev 03)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 31cc (rev 03)
00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 31d0 (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31e8 (rev 03)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 31d4 (rev 03)
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

sudo lshw-C network: no output

rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

sudo rfkill unblock all:
no output

dmesg | grep -i firmware

```
[    0.039204] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    2.644892] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin failed with error -2
[    2.644895] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin. Disabling runtime power management.
[    2.644897] i915 0000:00:02.0: DMC firmware homepage: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/firmware
```

dmesg | grep -i -e 0280 -e sdio

```
[    0.028000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
```

There are four Hardware-IDs found through the Windows 10 Device Manager:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3165&SUBSYS_80108086&REV_81
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3165&SUBSYS_80108086
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3165&CC_02800
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3165&CC_0280
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -i -e 0280 -e  sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there a setting in the BIOS to enable/disable wifi? We see nothing resembling wireless so far.

Comment: I can't find any, and I'd be surprised if it was turned off in the BIOS, since there are no problems with wifi whatsoever when using Windows 10 on the same machine.

Comment: Can you go into Windows device manager go into properties for wifi, detail tab,  and get the hardware ID and post it

Comment: Updated to show the Hardware IDs.

Comment: Have you checked the manufacturers web site to see if a BIOS update is available?

Comment: There seems to be a driver package available, but I'm not sure for what purpose. I don't see anything labelled "BIOS" in there. http://www.trekstor.de/products/notebook/detail-notebook/product/SURFBOOK%20A13B-PO.html